# Using PHP & curl to check balance, doesn't work. Whats missing?

Tags: java, php, curl

I'm trying to utilize php and curl to check my balance on one of my creditcards.

From what I understand, I need to send user_id and password together with other post-data to a page that responses with "LOGON OK", next step will be to sen more post-data to another page (not there yet) to finally access the balance of my creditcard.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
$username = '8311111234';
$password = 'my_pass';
$epochTime=round(microtime(true)*1000); //Epoch time in milliseconds
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://nettbank.edb.com/Logon/logon/step1");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "p_tranid=".$epochTime."&p_errorScreen=LOGON_REPOST_ERROR&n_bank=&empty_pwd=&user_id=".$username."&password=".$password);

if(!file_exists($cookie) || !is_writable($cookie)){
    echo 'Cookie file missing or not writable.';
    exit;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd()."/cert_okq8.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://nettbank.edb.com/Logon/index.jsp');

$response=curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'error:'.curl_error($ch);
}
echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```

When I do login with Chrome I can trace the connection with this info:

```
General
Remote Address:139.112.170.6:443
Request URL:https://nettbank.edb.com/Logon/logon/step1;jsessionid=0000RVzwfaiTxlm7IpeElaPliil:-1
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Length:6200
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Fri, 07 Aug 2015 14:23:37 GMT
Expires:Mon, 01 Jan 2001 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=631
P3P:CP='IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT'
Pragma:no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=2592000
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,nb;q=0.2
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:110
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=0000RVzwhaiTxlm7IpeElaPliil:-1; BIGipServerpool_evry_eBank-Person-Prod_81=130513881.20736.0000; __utmt=1; __utma=66339281.1672123597.1438628660.1438953141.1438996951.6; __utmb=66630281.1.10.1438456951; __utmc=66659281; __utmz=66639281.1438658660.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:nettbank.edb.com
Origin:https://nettbank.edb.com
Referer:https://nettbank.edb.com/Logon/index.jsp
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
p_tranid:1438957378657
p_errorScreen:LOGON_REPOST_ERROR
n_bank:
empty_pwd:
user_id:8311111234
password:my_pass
```

There is an app (bankdroid) for android that does this login, but I'm having trouble understanding the Java-code.
The actual code for login:
https://github.com/liato/android-bankdroid/blob/master/bankdroid-legacy/src/main/java/com/liato/bankdroid/banking/banks/OKQ8.java

The certificate:
https://github.com/liato/android-bankdroid/blob/master/bankdroid-legacy/src/main/res/raw/cert_okq8.pem

My actual code returns:

```
En feil oppstod under pålogging. Vennligst prøv igjen senere.
```

But as I can understand from the bankdroid-code

```
if (!response.contains("LOGON_OK")) {
```

The response should contain "LOGON_OK" instead of what I'm receiving above.

What am I missing?

Best Regards
Niclas

Comment: Hopefully those aren't valid credentials..

Comment: Have you verified the path to your cert?

Comment: People actually trust an external app to handle logging into their bank account? Amazing! As to your problem, banks will (should) have a number of security features designed to **stop** bots trying to access their accounts, so this is not going to be an easy project if you are just beginning building http bots

Comment: chris85:  They're not valid credentials ;) And its just a balance-account, cant do anything with it, except checking the balance.

Comment: Ooh @Steve let me point you toward this -> https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/382273/141202_API_Report_FINAL.PDF

Comment: @Half Crazed: Yes I've verified the path to the cert. I did also change the code to curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd()."/cert_okq8.pem");
But it's still the same.